# Imbalaced-learn doesn't work even it has been installed

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, imbalanced-data, imblearn

This is odd, I'm using 3.7 python and my libraries the dependent to imbalanced-learn is satistied too. However, when I import the library in Jupyter, it produces error. Can anyone please advice?

```
--> 13 from imblearn import FunctionSampler
        14 #model metrics
        15 from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imblearn'
```

Versions:

- imbalanced-learn      0.6.2
- imblearn              0.0

Comment: are you sure you installed it in the right enviornment?

Comment: Hi, I'm a beginner using Visual Studio Code, how do I know if I install in the right environment and what should I do going forward?

Answer (score 0):

Check that you are running in the correct [python environment in vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments), then it should work.